# Use two next button in twitter bootstrap form wizard

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am using two next button (.button-next) in my twitter bootstrap form wizard. 1st one with label "Save" and 2nd one with label "Save and Continue". Now, in onNext event how can I track, from which button the request come from?

I have tried to grab button text with `$(this).text();` which is not working.

**CODE:**

```
onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    success.hide();
                    error.hide();

                    if (form.valid() == false) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (index === 2)
                    {
                        if($(this).text() === 'save') // this condition is not working
                        {
                            return false; 
                        }

                        var url = $('#desurl').val();
                        var language = $('#language').val();
                        var description = $('#description').val();
                        var features = $('#features').val();


                        $.ajax({
                            method: "POST",
                            url: url,
                            data: { language : language, description : description, features : features },
                            dataType: "json",
                            complete: function(){

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    handleTitle(tab, navigation, index);
                }
```

Comment: Can you post the current code please?

Comment: @ManojKumar code added

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="demo,php" method="post">
  <button name="whichbutton" type="submit" value="btn1">Save</button>
  <button name="whichbutton" type="submit" value="btn2">Save on Continue</button>
</form>
```

if php

echo $POST["whichbutton"]

link here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp

Comment: I have mentioned clearly that it is in "twitter bootstrap form wizard". Please first read the question carefully.